# Change the icon of the push notification status bar on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My app icon is blue/red and when I receive a push notification the icon on status bar is the same app icon(blue/red). I want the icon of the status bar be a transparent and white version.

My ionic project is using [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#-plugin-api) to receive push notifications. The official docs of the plugin theres nothing about how to configure the icon of the status bar notification.

Comment: ... android? iOS? WP8?

Comment: sorry.. Android and IOS

Comment: I'm not really understand your question actually.

Comment: @DanielFaria How is that possible using new plugin!!any idea.. I am stuck at the same problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like what you’d want isn’t possible with that library.

#### On iOS

According to the documentation, the notification icon [is automatically set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html) to your app’s small icon (`Icon-Small.png`):

> In the banner, iOS displays your notification message and the small version of your app icon.

Unless you change the small version of the app icon, this is not possible at all on iOS.

#### On Android

Using the Android APIs this would be simple with [`Notification.Builder#setSmallIcon(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)), but the library you’re using [hard-codes that icon](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/8317414f3b310f628468f0d58838d98008b22da1/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L104) to the application’s icon.

You’d need to modify the library to accept other icons. It’s likely that this has not been implemented so that the behaviour would be consistent on all platforms.

**UPDATE**

Now with [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) is completely possible.

Comment: in local push notification its possible to change icon

Answer (score 4):

```
    private void shownotification(String message, Context context) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setContentTitle("Jaswinderwadali").setContentText(message)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.Mypic);
    Notification notification = mNotifyBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Its For android change icon of notification in status bar  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.Mypic)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a icon named ic_stat_onesignal_default in your drawables directory which will be shown instead of OneSignal's default bell icon.

Comment: This is for OneSignal only.