# App icon not showing when notification is received in meteor app

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

Whenever I receive a push notification on ios for my meteor/Cordova app I get the Cordova logo instead of my app logo.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Which icons you have added in your image assets?

Comment: may this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897623/change-the-icon-of-the-push-notification-status-bar-on-android-and-ios